# How to find local git repositories without remote origin?

Tags: git, repository, git-remote

Local git repositories often start out without a remote repository.
How can one find all those repos which haven't been pushed yet (=have no remote origin attached to them)?

Recursive folder searches are slow.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a fast solution via ripgrep:

```bash
rg --files-without-match --hidden --glob '**/.git/config' remote
```

searches recursively for all .git/config files not containing `remote` (tested on win10).